# How to edit specific event in calendar using EventKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I want to programmatically edit a specific stored event in calendar. I think it can be done by event identifier, but I don't know a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library [JSCalendarManager](https://github.com/jingsh/JSCalendarManager) it will help you a lot and have all methods ready and abstracted for your convenience.

To update an event use the following method

```
 /*!
 @method     updateEvent: withTitle: location: startTime: endTime: description: URL: completionHandler:
 @discussion Call this method to retrieve and update an event.
 */
-(void)updateEvent:(NSString *)eventIdentifier
         withTitle:(NSString *)title
          location:(NSString *)location
         startTime:(NSDate *)start
           endTime:(NSDate *)end
       description:(NSString *)descrition
               URL:(NSString *)urlString
 completionHandler:(eventsOperationCompletionHandler)handler;
```